# react material ui not responsive when opened in mobile browser

Tags: reactjs, responsive

I'm trying to build a mobile web application using react material ui library.

But it seems the material UI components are not responsive. They display very well on desktop, but when I open it on my mobile browser, the fonts are very small.

Isn't material UI meant to be used to build mobile App? Why it's even not responsive?

[image]

Comment: I guess you didn't add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in the `<head>` section of your document.

Comment: @pawel, thanks for pointing out. That's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You must add the directive  in the  section.

Add  to your project in which you initiate the application:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page. It varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

A  viewport element gives the browser's instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width = device-width part sets the width of the page to the screen-width of the device.

The initial-scale = 1.0 part set the first zoom in the browser.

Comment: Just made my... uhm... night :D

Answer (score 6):

## Material @4 and @5

you have a `index.html` file in your public folder.
add this line at the beginning of your `<head>` tag.

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
```

[Reference](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/usage/#responsive-meta-tag)

Answer (score 2):

https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/

https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#columns-gutters-and-margins

Use the breakpoint like:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid xs={12} md={6} lg={5} item>    
  </Grid>
  <Grid xs={12} md={6} lg={7} item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you did add the viewport, you can use breakpoint to make your webpage responsive as suggested by [@Lane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415866/react-material-ui-not-responsive-when-opened-in-mobile-browser/69324560#answer-61995357).

**Steps:**

1. Declare a variable.
   This returns true if the breakpoint is hit otherwise false.

   ```js
   const matches = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');
   ```

   Reference: https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/
2. Use the `sx` props to set the width using the variable from step 1 with ternary operator

   ```html
   <Paper sx={{ width: matches === false ? '40vw' : '80vw' }} />
   ```

   Reference: https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

**Example:**

```js
const Component = () => {
    const matches = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');

    return (
      <Box
         sx={{
           '& .MuiTextField-root': { **width: matches === false ? '35vw' : '70vw'** },
        }}
      >
         {/* ... */}
      </Box >
    );
}
```